# How do you disappear using Lucario in SSBB?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

I once accidentally made Lucario disappear in SSBB, but I can't do it again. How do you disappear using Lucario in SSBB?

Comment: Do you mean his counter, which can cause him to suddenly appear to vanish and then attack a foe?  This is a move he performs with Down-B, where if someone hits you as you perform it, he'll do that.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably thinking of [Double Team](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Double_Team), Lucario's down special move. It's a counterattack that causes it to temporarily vanish before attacking from the side; as a counterattack, it only activates if it's hit by a blockable attack during the move.